# Maven: Attempting to create memory dump for unit tests

Tags: maven-2

I have difficulty creating a memory dump for my unit tests which produce out of memory errors.

My MAVEN_OPTS contains the following:

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Temp
```

However, when I run my unit tests from the command line using "mvn install", I do not get any such memory dump when the OutOfMemoryError occurs.

How do I get the memory dump?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven (`surefire-plugin` to be precise) by default creates new JVM for running tests. `MAVEN_OPTS` variable is used by the JVM running maven itself, but not forked test JVM. To change settings of that JVM, use the following code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Temp</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ... -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Where do I add this plugin? In the pom of the project whose tests I am running?

Comment: @DJoyce: yes, I updated my answer to show the exact context where you place that code snippet.

Comment: I've tried that now, and even though I observed an OutOfMemoryError, there is still no entry in C:\Temp. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DJoyce: your options are wrong, it should be: '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError', not `-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. I corrected my answer (C&P of your question).